# Update magento price using custom attributes

Tags: magento

I am a newbie to Magento Framework.

Can any one tell me how to add custom pricing to products based on custom attributes.

For example: I would not enter price or I will enter a dummy number for price in admin panel and other attributes like weight and type of item and category.

Based on the category, weight and type of item I want to calculate the actual price something

like `price=weight*category+typeOfItem` And also if there is any special price to the product it should also apply along with tier prices

I have created a custom module using Alan Storm's Blog but I am unable to override the pricing. Sometimes it works in the product listing page but never works with 'tier' price.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use a configurable product for this, assuming you don't have a huge range of weights and products

Otherwise maybe look at overwriting the 
getFinalPrice() method in the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price model.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and suggestions. After waiting for long I thought of writing override custom module and I did the same.

I used Alan Storms tutorials for creating the module and overrode Product as well Price modules

But no luck any ways thanks for your reply.